# Etale cohomology of $Spec(ₚ^{\text{sep}}((t)))$

Tags: group-cohomology, local-field, etale-cohomology, galois-cohomology

I am thinking about how norms $ν : L ⭢ ℤ$ on higher local fields could induce long exact sequences in different cohomologies.

- $ₚ^{\text{sep}}((t)),ℚₚ^{\text{sep}}$, and $ℂ$ are a local fields. What is the easiest way to show that their Brauer group vanishes?
- $ₚ^{\text{sep}}((t₁,...,t_{n+1})),ℚₚ^{\text{sep}}((t₁,...,t_{n}))$, and $ℂ((t₁,...,t_{n}))$ are higher local fields. What is the easiest way to find their étale cohomology?

I was hoping that they would produce the cohomology ring of 0.

Comment: Étale cohomology with which coefficients? It's going to be difficult to compute for all possible coefficients. Btw, because all these are just fields, étale cohomology for these reduces to just Galois cohomology.

Comment: The format needs to be fixed. You have used some special characters that are not available on every OS. I suggest to use math environments instead, always, also for simple formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer the first question:

If a field is separably closed, then the Brauer group vanishes, because the absolute Galois group is trivial, this covers $\Bbb Q_p^{\mathrm{sep}}$ and $\Bbb C$.

To see that $\overline{\Bbb F_p}((t))$ has vanishing Brauer group, we can use local class field theory. Note that we have $\overline{\Bbb F_p}((t))=\bigcup_{n \geq 1}\Bbb F_p((t))(\zeta_{p^n-1})$. Therefore, we get $$\mathrm{Br}(\overline{\Bbb F_p}((t)))=\varinjlim_{n \geq 1}\mathrm{Br}(\Bbb F_p((t))(\zeta_{p^n-1}))$$
Where the direct limit is taken over inflation maps. But each $\Bbb F_p((t))(\zeta_{p^n-1})$ is a local field, so local class field theory tells us what those Brauer groups and the inflation map look like: More generally, for an extension of non-archimedean local fields $L/K$; there's a commutative diagram:

$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
\mathrm{Br}(K) @>{\cong}>> \Bbb Q/\Bbb Z\\ @V{\mathrm{Inf}}VV @VV{\cdot [L:K]}V\\
\mathrm{Br}(L) @>>{\cong}> \Bbb Q/\Bbb Z
\end{CD}$

Where the horizontal maps are the local invariant maps.

This actually implies in our situation that the direct limit is zero: it suffices that for all $n$ and all $\alpha \in \mathrm{Br}(\Bbb F_p((t))(\zeta_{p^n-1})$, there is some $m$ such that $\alpha$ is in the kernel of the inflation map $\mathrm{Br}(\Bbb F_p((t))(\zeta_{p^n-1})\to \Bbb F_p((t))(\zeta_{p^{nm}-1})$. But using the commutative diagram above, we can just take $m$ to be the order of $\alpha$, because the inflation map corresponds after applying invariant isomorphisms to multiplication by $[\Bbb F_p((t))(\zeta_{p^{nm}-1}):\Bbb F_p((t))(\zeta_{p^n-1})]=m$.

Basically the same argument shows that $\Bbb Q_p^{ur}$ has trivial Brauer group.

Comment: Thanks this answer is really great.